# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Theme' not found'

Tags: laravel, view, controller

local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Theme' not found' in C:\a38e1ce7fd43754068afd6b72d340756:4

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i try to go to any route of the controller and  this error occur on all routes of this controller